# Use same settings for several environmants in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to build several environments on AWS using Terraform. Most of the settings apply to all environments - how can I avoid code duplication?

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "app" {
  name = "${var.appName}"
  description = ""
} 

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "app_env" {
  name                = "${var.envName}"
  application         = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.app.name}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.8.4 running Multi-container Docker 17.09.1-ce (Generic)"

  #the same for all envs
  setting { 
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = "vpc-myVpcId"
  },
   #changes for each env
   setting {
        namespace =  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
        name =  "SERVICE_NAME",
        value =  "${var.ServiceName}"
    },

  resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "app" {
  name = "${var.appName}"
  description = ""
} 

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "app_env_2" {
  name                = "${var.envName}"
  application         = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.app.name}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.8.4 running Multi-container Docker 17.09.1-ce (Generic)"

  #the same for all envs
  setting { 
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = "vpc-myVpcId"
  },
   #changes for each env
   setting {
        namespace =  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
        name =  "SERVICE_NAME",
        value =  "${var.ServiceName_2}"
    },


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that.

1. Use environment variables as show here: [variables](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html)
2. Use a global module that provides default variables [modules](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/modules.html)

Both have their pros and cons. Env vars, give you the freedom to not write more code, but are runtime env specific.

Well, modules, require writing a module :)